# Parsing difficult strings in CSV with python

Tags: python, csv

I'm building a parser for my Firefox history CSV. It includes lines like this one:

```
"2017-07-12 09:43:31","https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/should-there-always-be-a-comma-after-therefore-however-etc","punctuation - Should there always be a comma after ""therefore","However" etc.? - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange"
```

Is there an efficient way to deal with this (e.g. with some tools matching templates)? In theory, it should be possible to parse since it is always `"$DATE","$URL","$everything_else"` but I cannot use normal CSV parsers (many commas in lines) and my script matching only '","' also fails for these cases.

Additionally, the third field doesn't always exist and then the format is `"$DATE","$URL"`. But I think that's a minor problem then.

Comment: Are there ever commas in the url field? If not, then a simple `row.split(',',2)` would suffice?

Comment: what do you mean "many commas in line"? python CSV parser should work, assuming Firefox history is really CSV.

Comment: The sample line doesn't properly escape double quotes.  `""therefore","However"` should be `""therefore"",""However""`.  The line is ambiguous.

Comment: @match Oh, that is so simple. I used split before but I totally forgot about the maxsplit option. It does work this way in my case.
(If the order is changed however, this method wouln't work anymore.)

pbuck: With many commas I was referring to the page title that can and does contain commas sometimes.
Also, it doesn't escape quotes properly as Mark Tolonen said, it doesn't eve close quotes (as page titles are just shitty sometimes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better way to do this, but regular expressions would do the trick:

```
import re
capture = re.findall(r"^\"([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\",\"([^\"]+)\",?(.+)?$",csv_string)
```

which returns a list of lists (sample below).

```
[('2017-07-12 09:43:31', 'https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/should-there-always-be-a-comma-after-therefore-however-etc',   '"punctuation - Should there always be a comma after ""therefore","However" etc.? - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange"')]
```

Depending on what you want to do with the data, you might need to come up with an extra handler from there. If `i` represents your line number, you can access information by: `list_for_line[i][0]` for timestamp; `list_for_line[i][1]` for the url; and `list_for_line[i][2]` for the description.